# Facebook share button not sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have added a facebook share button to my app and it appears correctly o the page. I have used the following code:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

When I click the button it a popup appears with the correct content and I can click "Post to facebook"

When I do the item appears in my feed perfectly but nobody else can see it even though the privacy settings are correct.

Any ideas... ?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your share button code -->
  <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to put your code in the question not in a link to facebook docs that doesn't even point to a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider:

- Is the privacy set to "friends" or even "public" in the share popup?
- Is your App public? Set it public in the "App Review" section.

Make sure your friends actually go to your user profile to check out the posting, it may just not show up in their stream.

Comment: 2nd point... I just want to share the web link so do I really need an app? I have one but removed the app:id from the html as the code above did not include it.

Comment: you should always use an app, for any social plugin. no need for the app:id in the html, but you should load the js sdk correctly with your app id. just like in the generated code.

Comment: Yes, making the app public fixed it. I am not sure what I have made public though...

Comment: it´s just a setting so that other users can use your app, not just users with a role in the app.